# When uncertainty is calculated in non normalized eigenstates it doesn't give zero. Shouldn't it give zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose $\Psi$ is an eigenstate of observable $\text H$ with eigenvalue $E_1$. Then uncertainty in the value of $\text H$,
$(\Delta E)^2=\langle E^2\rangle-\langle E\rangle^2$ which gives,
$(\Delta E)^2=E_1^2\bigg(\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_1\rangle-\big|\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_1\rangle\big|^2\bigg)$
If the eigenstate is not normalized then the right hand side is not zero. But the measurement of $\text H$ on $\Psi$ must yield $E_1$ with no uncertainty.

Comment: Why do you think it should be zero if the eigenfunctions are not normalized?

Comment: If a state is unnormalized then $\langle {\cal O}\rangle_\Psi  = \frac{ \langle \Psi |  {\cal O} | \Psi \rangle }{ \langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle }$

Comment: Shoudn't the uncertainty be zero? @garyp

Comment: Normalizing a wave function is (effectively) multiplying the wave function by a *scalar* term: $\psi_{N}=A\psi_{UN}$. Not sure how/why its absence would lead to a zero eigenstate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the postulates of quantum mechanics that the expectation value of the observable corresponding to the hermitian operator $A$ in the normalized state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by $\langle A\rangle_\psi =\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$.
Alternatively, you can postulate that the expectation value is given by $\langle A \rangle_\psi = \frac{\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}$. See, for example, the [Dirac--von Neumann axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%E2%80%93von_Neumann_axioms)

Either way the normalization is necessary, because otherwise you have to give physical meaning to the normalization.

Edit: So the reason your calculation is giving a strange result is you are calculating expectation values wrong.